# win 10: linux subsystem multi tab bash

Tags: windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Is there a way to get multi tab bash windows for the linux subsystem in win 10?
something like conemu or Multi-Tab putty or console (http://sourceforge.net/projects/console/)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should be able to use something like MobaXterm and open multiple linux subsystem tabs. Take a look at this article and scroll down a bit to the demonstration video where he opens WSL tabs:

http://blog.mobatek.net/post/mobaxterm-new-release-9.0/

Also, as an aside, there is this UserVoice issue that appears to have been approved but is not implemented yet:

https://web.archive.org/web/20161204101149/https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/266908-command-prompt-console-bash-on-ubuntu-on-windo/suggestions/6509358-great-start-but-still-missing-one-of-my-cmd-desir

Comment: ahh cool did not know about wpdev on uservoice. On a side note, another feature i want is seperate wallpapers for each virtual desktop. Do you if there is something similar to wpdev.uservoice for a request like that? As far as i can tell there is just a code hack someone put together to get close to that feature.

Answer (score 15):

Windows Terminal worked quickly and easily for me: https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/p/windows-terminal-preview/9n0dx20hk701?activetab=pivot:overviewtab

Comment: yup am using this now. i would also recco this. https://github.com/microsoft/terminal

Comment: I really recommend this too.

Comment: how do you use it with bash?

Comment: @jimsmith, click the down arrow and select `ubuntu` (or whatever you name wsl)

Answer (score 8):

Something similar you can use is a common linux utility called screen. If not installed by default you can use `sudo apt install screen` once installed run `sudo screen`

You can now run the command `screen` to start a screen emulation, these are like invisible tabs. To create a new tab type: ctrl-"a" "c", to switch between tabs type ctrl-"a" "n"

This basically lets you have concurrent shells running. ctrl-"a" "d" detaches you back to your primary shell.

More can be found here: https://www.rackaid.com/blog/linux-screen-tutorial-and-how-to/

Comment: FYI after starting screen use `su John` or whatever your user is so you're not prancing around w root privs.

Answer (score 2):

You can just start a new instance of WSL instance of the same thing (eg: Start > Ubuntu ) and it will open up a new terminal (separate window) which operates on the same linux file system. It is simple although not another "Tab" but it should get your problem solved.

I use vi to edit files while I browse using other terminal window.

Comment: Why is this downvoted?

Comment: @ZenVentzi because de OP is asking for multitab, not about opening a new window, which clearly is possible

Answer (score -1):

I've started using [Hyper.js](https://hyper.is/) via https://superuser.com/a/1120008